# How to search for a string(attribute) efficiently in a large file which can be a text file or a log file?

Tags: search

I apologise for such a common question, but I indeed need a precise approach to solve this problem:
For example, consider the following scenarios:

1) Searching for a pattern in a text file written in English? [I used English here to stress the fact that the file is completely random and does not exhibit a common pattern or a behaviour which we can use to make our search efficient]? What can be the time complexity if the file is N Bytes in size?

2) Searching an attribute log file where every line is unique and have some attributes for example:

```
   TIMESTAMP1: attribute1a attribute 1b .... attribute1n 
   TIMESTAMP2: attribute2a attribute 2b .... attribute2n
   .
   .
   .
```

This scenario results in two possible cases, 1) With Timestamp sorted and 2) Timestamp unsorted.

Consider that files are as big as 600-700MBs. Also, what happens in cases when our RAM is large enough to load the entire file and when our RAM is mere 50-80 Bytes large?
It will be great if I can get help with the efficient approach that can be taken here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To break it down a bit: You need an efficient algorithm to search a string within another string? Also it is not clear to me what you mean with scenario #2. Maybe take a look at the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I need to search a string in another main string, but that main string happens to be a large file infact. Also, by scenario #2 I mean the given file is some sort of a log file where every line is unique, hence for searching we can index the file and create a hash out of it. Creating a hash for #1 may not be a good idea because the file is completely random and lines may be repeated. Again, hash is just an example for clarification.There could be other better approaches. Also, what would happen if the RAM is not large enough keep entire file? How do we perform search in that case?